# How to generate a pdf file using Word Template in Python?

Tags: python, ms-word, python-docx, pypdf

I need to generate the pdf file in Python. I have created a Word Template file (Word XML document) with placeholders in the document.

I populate the placeholders dynamically and can create a word document. However, I would like to convert this document generated into a PDF file.

BTW, I am trying this on Linux server. Any idea how this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

You can use LibreOffice to convert docx to pdf

```
libreoffice --convert-to pdf file_path.docx --outdir   output_path.pdf
```